# Wp Gutenberg, add element in position absolute within a block

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

i'm trying to write an HOC that add a decoration within a set of "allowed blocks", at moment it works fine inside the editor page, but nothing is showed on frontend (the "decoration element" is not rendered.

i need help to find what i'm doing wrong, someone can help me?

what i need is to have this element in position absolute within my blocks defined in supportedBlockTypes variable

```html
<div className="decoration">
                            <div className={ `decoration__box` }>
                                <div className={ `decoration__image position-absolute translate-middle ${ boxDecorationColor } ${ boxDecorationTopPosition } ${ boxDecorationLeftPosition }` }>
                                    <DecorationSvg
                                        rotation={ boxDecorationRotation }
                                        opacity={ boxDecorationOpacity }
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

```js
import { PanelBody, RangeControl, SelectControl, ToggleControl } from '@wordpress/components';

import { Fragment } from '@wordpress/element';
import { InspectorControls } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { formatClassName } from "@gutenberg/js/scripts/classNamesUtils";
import {
    BOX_DECORATION_COLORS,
    BOX_DECORATION_OPACITY,
    BOX_DECORATION_POSITIONING,
    BOX_DECORATION_SIZES,
} from "@gutenberg/js/const/boxDecoration";
import { DecorationSvg } from "@gutenberg/js/icons";

const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;

const supportedBlockTypes = [
    'ui/layout-column',
    'ui/component-image',
    'ui/component-split-banner',
];

const addWithBoxDecorationAttributes = ( settings, name ) => {
    if ( ! supportedBlockTypes.includes( name ) ) {
        return settings;
    }

    const additionalAttributes = {
        isDecorationEnabled: {
            type: 'boolean',
            default: false,
        },
        boxDecorationColor: {
            type: 'string',
            default: BOX_DECORATION_COLORS[ 0 ].value,
        },
        boxDecorationSize: {
            type: 'string',
            default: BOX_DECORATION_SIZES[ 1 ].value,
        },
        boxDecorationTopPosition: {
            type: 'string',
            default: BOX_DECORATION_POSITIONING.TOP[ 0 ].value,
        },
        boxDecorationLeftPosition: {
            type: 'string',
            default: BOX_DECORATION_POSITIONING.LEFT[ 0 ].value,
        },
        boxDecorationRotation: {
            type: 'string',
            default: BOX_DECORATION_POSITIONING.ROTATION[ 0 ].value,
        },
        boxDecorationOpacity: {
            type: 'string',
            default: BOX_DECORATION_OPACITY[ 8 ].value,
        },
    };

    settings.attributes = { ...settings.attributes, ...additionalAttributes };

    return settings;
};

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'ui-plugin/with-box-decoration/attributes',
    addWithBoxDecorationAttributes
);

/**
 * Create HOC
 */

const withBoxDecoration = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        const {
            attributes: {
                boxDecorationSize, boxDecorationTopPosition,
                boxDecorationLeftPosition, boxDecorationRotation,
                boxDecorationOpacity, boxDecorationColor, isDecorationEnabled,
            },
            setAttributes,
            name,
        } = props;

        if ( ! supportedBlockTypes.includes( name ) ) {
            return <BlockEdit { ...props } />;
        }

        const onChangeSetIsDecorationEnabled = ( value ) => {
            setAttributes( { isDecorationEnabled: value } );
        };

        const onChangeSetDecorationColor = ( newValue ) => {
            setAttributes( { boxDecorationColor: newValue } );
        };

        const onChangeSetDecorationSize = ( newValue ) => {
            const selectedOption = BOX_DECORATION_SIZES[ newValue ];
            const selectedValue = selectedOption ? selectedOption.value : '';
            setAttributes( { boxDecorationSize: selectedValue } );
        };

        const onChangeSetDecorationTopPosition = ( newValue ) => {
            const selectedOption = BOX_DECORATION_POSITIONING.TOP[ newValue ];
            const selectedValue = selectedOption ? selectedOption.value : '';
            setAttributes( { boxDecorationTopPosition: selectedValue } );
        };

        const onChangeSetDecorationLeftPosition = ( newValue ) => {
            const selectedOption = BOX_DECORATION_POSITIONING.LEFT[ newValue ];
            const selectedValue = selectedOption ? selectedOption.value : '';
            setAttributes( { boxDecorationLeftPosition: selectedValue } );
        };

        const onChangeSetDecorationRotation = ( newValue ) => {
            const selectedOption = BOX_DECORATION_POSITIONING.ROTATION[ newValue ];
            const selectedValue = selectedOption ? selectedOption.value : '';
            setAttributes( { boxDecorationRotation: selectedValue } );
        };

        const onChangeSetDecorationOpacity = ( newValue ) => {
            const selectedOption = BOX_DECORATION_OPACITY[ newValue ];
            const selectedValue = selectedOption ? selectedOption.value : '';
            setAttributes( { boxDecorationOpacity: selectedValue } );
        };

        const getCurrentLabelByValue = ( options, value ) => {
            const matchingOption = options.find( option => option.value === value );
            return matchingOption ? matchingOption.label : '';
        };

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockEdit { ...props } />

                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody initialOpen={ false } title="Box Decoration">
                        <p className="text-muted">
                            This menu allow to Enable/Disable box decoration.
                        </p>
                        <ToggleControl
                            help={ isDecorationEnabled ? 'Decoration enabled' : 'Decoration disabled' }
                            checked={ isDecorationEnabled }
                            onChange={ onChangeSetIsDecorationEnabled }
                        />
                        <p className="text-muted">
                            This menu allow to choose the decoration color.
                        </p>
                        <SelectControl
                            label="Decoration Color"
                            value={ boxDecorationColor }
                            onChange={ onChangeSetDecorationColor }
                            options={ BOX_DECORATION_COLORS }
                        />
                        <p className="text-muted">
                            This range controls the decoration position from TOP.
                        </p>
                        <RangeControl
                            label="Position from TOP"
                            initialPosition={ 0 }
                            allowReset
                            step={ 1 }
                            withInputField={ false }
                            separatorType="none"
                            isShiftStepEnabled
                            railColor="red"
                            value={ boxDecorationTopPosition }
                            onChange={ onChangeSetDecorationTopPosition }
                            min={ 0 }
                            max={ BOX_DECORATION_POSITIONING.TOP.length - 1 }
                            renderTooltipContent={ () => getCurrentLabelByValue( BOX_DECORATION_POSITIONING.TOP, boxDecorationTopPosition ) }
                        />
                        <p className="text-muted">
                            This range controls the decoration position from LEFT.
                        </p>
                        <RangeControl
                            label="Position from LEFT"
                            initialPosition={ 0 }
                            allowReset
                            step={ 1 }
                            withInputField={ false }
                            separatorType="none"
                            isShiftStepEnabled
                            railColor="red"
                            value={ boxDecorationLeftPosition }
                            onChange={ onChangeSetDecorationLeftPosition }
                            min={ 0 }
                            max={ BOX_DECORATION_POSITIONING.LEFT.length - 1 }
                            renderTooltipContent={ () => getCurrentLabelByValue( BOX_DECORATION_POSITIONING.LEFT, boxDecorationLeftPosition ) }
                        />
                        <p className="text-muted">
                            This range controls the decoration rotation.
                        </p>
                        <RangeControl
                            label="Decoration ROTATION"
                            allowReset
                            step={ 1 }
                            withInputField={ false }
                            separatorType="none"
                            isShiftStepEnabled
                            railColor="red"
                            value={ boxDecorationRotation }
                            onChange={ onChangeSetDecorationRotation }
                            min={ 0 }
                            max={ BOX_DECORATION_POSITIONING.ROTATION.length - 1 }
                            renderTooltipContent={ () => getCurrentLabelByValue( BOX_DECORATION_POSITIONING.ROTATION, boxDecorationRotation ) }
                        />
                        <p className="text-muted">
                            This range controls the decoration opacity.
                        </p>
                        <RangeControl
                            label="Decoration OPACITY"
                            allowReset
                            step={ 1 }
                            withInputField={ false }
                            separatorType="none"
                            isShiftStepEnabled
                            railColor="red"
                            value={ boxDecorationOpacity }
                            onChange={ onChangeSetDecorationOpacity }
                            min={ 0 }
                            max={ BOX_DECORATION_OPACITY.length - 1 }
                            renderTooltipContent={ () => getCurrentLabelByValue( BOX_DECORATION_OPACITY, boxDecorationOpacity ) }
                        />
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>

                { isDecorationEnabled && (
                    <div className="decoration">
                        <div className={ `decoration__box` }>
                            <div className={ `decoration__image position-absolute translate-middle ${ boxDecorationColor } ${ boxDecorationTopPosition } ${ boxDecorationLeftPosition }` }>
                                <DecorationSvg
                                    rotation={ boxDecorationRotation }
                                    opacity={ boxDecorationOpacity }
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ) }
            </Fragment>
        );
    };
} );

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'editor.BlockEdit',
    'ui-plugin/with-box-decoration/hoc',
    withBoxDecoration
);

const addWithBoxDecorationExtraProps = ( saveElementProps, block, attributes ) => {
    if ( ! supportedBlockTypes.includes( block.name ) ) {
        return saveElementProps;
    }

    const {
        boxDecorationSize,
        boxDecorationTopPosition,
        boxDecorationLeftPosition,
        boxDecorationColor,
    } = attributes;

    const className = formatClassName(
        saveElementProps.className || "",
        boxDecorationSize,
        boxDecorationTopPosition,
        boxDecorationLeftPosition,
        boxDecorationColor,
    );

    return {
        ...saveElementProps,
        className,
    };
};

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps',
    'ui-plugin/with-box-decoration/extra-props',
    addWithBoxDecorationExtraProps
);
```